# How to add images to android drawable resources in expo without running expo prebuild to create an android folder

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

I am trying to use [react-native-quick-actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-quick-actions) with expo using its [config plugin](https://github.com/expo/config-plugins/tree/main/packages/react-native-quick-actions) as suggested in [expo forum](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/app-shortcuts). The shortcuts are working, though i am unable to set a custom image for the shortcut on android. According to the docs, I need to add the images in drawable folder, in android.
I am aware running `expo prebuild` does generate an android folder, but I am trying to stay away from it, since its just a few images.

I tried using assets and require, but that does not work.

I am aware of config plugins might be able to move files during `expo prebuild` (when it gets built on EAS) but can't find one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way using config plugins. It runs when we run `expo prebuild`, either on the local machine or in EAS, and copies the contents of the specified folders into drawable folder in android.

One can modify it for iOS I believe.

Create a File `withDrawableAssets.ts` and paste the below code.
You will need to compile it to javascript before using it.

```js
import type { ConfigPlugin } from "@expo/config-plugins";

import { existsSync, mkdirSync, lstatSync, readdirSync, copyFileSync } from "fs";
import { join, basename } from "path";

import { withDangerousMod } from "@expo/config-plugins";

const androidFolderPath = ["app", "src", "main", "res", "drawable"];

const withDrawableAssets: ConfigPlugin<string | string[]> = (expoConfig, files) =>
  withDangerousMod(expoConfig, [
    "android",
    (modConfig) => {
      if (modConfig.modRequest.platform === "android") {
        const androidDwarablePath = join(modConfig.modRequest.platformProjectRoot, ...androidFolderPath);
        if (!Array.isArray(files)) {
          files = [files];
        }

        files.forEach((file) => {
          const isFile = lstatSync(file).isFile();
          if (isFile) {
            copyFileSync(file, join(androidDwarablePath, basename(file)));
          } else {
            copyFolderRecursiveSync(file, androidDwarablePath);
          }
        });
      }
      return modConfig;
    },
  ]);

async function copyFolderRecursiveSync(source: string, target: string) {
  if (!existsSync(target)) mkdirSync(target);

  const files = readdirSync(source);

  files.forEach(async (file) => {
    const sourcePath = join(source, file);
    const targetPath = join(target, file);

    if (lstatSync(sourcePath).isDirectory()) {
      copyFolderRecursiveSync(sourcePath, targetPath);
    } else {
      copyFileSync(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
  });
}

export default withDrawableAssets;
```

usage
in app.json

```json
{
  "expo": {
      ... // rest of app.json
      "plugins": [["./withDrawableAssets.js","./assets/shortcuts"] ,"@config-plugins/react-native-quick-actions"]
//./assets/shortcuts is the name of the name of folder I wanted to copy to the drawable folder 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works like a charm!! thank ..
here is the js code

```
    const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { withDangerousMod } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

const androidFolderPath = ["app", "src", "main", "res", "drawable"];

const withDrawableAssets = function (expoConfig, files) {
  return withDangerousMod(expoConfig, [
    "android",
    function (modConfig) {
      if (modConfig.modRequest.platform === "android") {
        const androidDwarablePath = path.join(
          modConfig.modRequest.platformProjectRoot,
          ...androidFolderPath
        );

        if (!Array.isArray(files)) {
          files = [files];
        }

        files.forEach(function (file) {
          const isFile = fs.lstatSync(file).isFile();
          if (isFile) {
            fs.copyFileSync(file, path.join(androidDwarablePath, path.basename(file)));
          } else {
            copyFolderRecursiveSync(file, androidDwarablePath);
          }
        });
      }
      return modConfig;
    },
  ]);
};

function copyFolderRecursiveSync(source, target) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(target)) fs.mkdirSync(target);

  const files = fs.readdirSync(source);

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    const sourcePath = path.join(source, file);
    const targetPath = path.join(target, file);

    if (fs.lstatSync(sourcePath).isDirectory()) {
      copyFolderRecursiveSync(sourcePath, targetPath);
    } else {
      fs.copyFileSync(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = withDrawableAssets;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).